# Is there a way to make `something;` do anything?

Tags: c++

From time to time when looking through code, I see people write lines such as:

```
something;
```

People always say that such a *statement* is stupid and does nothing. I started to wonder if there is a way in C++ to make it do anything.

The word *statement* is pretty well defined in C++. So I actually have two questions:

1. Is there a way to make such a line do anything, with out using a macro?
2. Is there a way to make something an object, so `something;` is actually an identifier statement (I hope I understand and used the term correctly), and does anything. I guess that  a macro makes it not an identifier statement.

So the code example with a macro:

something.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    #include "something.hpp"
    something;
    return 0;
}
```

something.hpp:

```
#define something std::cout<<"It's something!\n"
```

Of course then `something;` does something.

Is there a way to implement `something.hpp` so that it does not use a macro, and preferably defines some class and makes `something` an instance of it and executes user written code.

The placement of `include`. Is chosen on purpose so it is possible to inject any code. E.g:

```
class T{};
T something;
```

Note that I believe that my second question is answered by [templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef) who addressed the previous version of question.

Comment: About #4, it's an *expression-statement*. In fact, a null statement is also an expression-statement, but with no expression, the expression being optional.

Comment: It's really not very clear what you're asking. Can you include some actual code? Are you literally just wondering whether it's possible to have `identifier;` do something? When would you ever have encountered this in real code? You say "from time to time", well, if that's the case, presumably that code *does* do something and you should include it here.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to give meaning to a statement that has no meaning within the language?

Comment: @meagar Yes, this is precisely what I am asking about, not sure what is unclear. Where I found it. Students' codes can be very creative. I saw a question on SO with similar code and started wondering if there is a language construct other than macro, that makes it do anything.

Comment: If `something` is a single identifier and not a language keyword its use like that would be a compiler error unless it were previously declared.  If it is declared as a variable that's in scope then the statement is essentially a no-op.

Comment: sometimes i use `0;` so i can bung in a breakpoint when debugging. So I guess it isuseful

Comment: @Ed Or just any pointless statements in general, like `vector.size();` I do that in C# all the time.

Comment: @remyabel - You must like typing :-)

Comment: @Ed But is `0;` valid code in C#? I don't know.

Comment: @remyabel - probably - cannot think why not

Comment: In Java and possibly C# a free-standing expression is not a valid statement -- it must be assigned to something or otherwise used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a draft copy of the C++11 ISO standard, from which I think we can safely say that the answer is no. A statement of the form

```
identifier;
```

is an expression statement. The spec (§6.2.1) says that

> The expression is evaluated and its value is discarded.

So what does the expression `identifier` evaluate to? Well, it's an identifier expression, which the spec (§5.1.1/6) says that

> The result is the entity denoted by the identifier.

So the effect of this expression is "evaluate to the entity given by `identifier` and then discard the result." There's no choice involved here, so this expression should always have no effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to define or tap-in into this evaluation? The fact that result is discarded is not enough, comma operator is useful too. I was thinking that maybe it would be possible to define some kind operator to define behaviour for such statement.

Comment: @templatetypedef - it does have an effect. Uses the CPU, time and memory. Just being pedantic!

Comment: @EdHeal Are you sure about that? If the expression has no effect, the compiler is perfectly free to optimize it out.

Comment: @luk32 Since the language defines the behavior as "evaluate to `identifier` and discard the result," I don't think there's any way to "tap into" it.

Comment: @templatetypedef - It may or may not do. But one cannot make a sweeping statement that it does not have an effect because it may do

Comment: @EdHeal A valid point. According to the spec, there is no effect of that statement *that would be visible to the rest of the program.* The statement may have an effect on the computer due to the way that the language is implemented, as long as those effects aren't visible to the rest of the program.

Comment: @templatetypedef - But it may do - consider multi-threaded programs. Now there is a battlefield that is sometimes difficult to get out of the trenches.

Comment: @EdHeal In that case, though, the language specification still makes guarantees about what might happen, either by saying that the program is nondeterministic (meaning that there aren't any guarantees on the timing) or by saying that certain operations can't impact certain other parts of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Not all expression statements are no-ops. They can be no-ops if they have no side effects or if they are a null statement. For example:

```
vector.size(); // Did nothing with the variable
; // null statement
0; // Random zero in the middle of code, confuse readers galore
   // or use as a breakpoint
doSomething(); // Do something
```

So in your case, I can't see any practical reason for why a student would write a variable followed by a semi-colon by itself unless it's a typo or used as a breakpoint.

Comment: I am not saying they knew what they were doing =). It was a code that did nothing. I just saw such piece of code more than once. I was wondering is there a way to define behaviour for such statement.